# Is there other observational evidence apart from CMB that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

When I search about the homogeneity and isotropy of the universe, I always find that the CMB and the smoothness of temperature are good observational evidence to suppose that our universe is homogeneous and isotropic on a large scale.
My question is: if there is any other evidence observational data that gives us that assumption of our universe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use supernovae to test anisotropy. See  Ronggen and Zhongliang, 2011, Direction dependence of the acceleration in type Ia supernovae, http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0941

Testing for anisotropy using galaxies: Longo, "Detection of a Dipole in the Handedness of Spiral Galaxies with Redshifts z ~ 0.04," 2011, http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2815

For homogeneity, you can basically pick any astronomical observable you like, and just test whether it's the same all across the sky. For example, you could look at the average sizes of galaxies, or the abundance of light elements.